# Select fields in linq statement from a csv string of field names

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking to dynamically select fields from a linq query where the fields names are in a csv string.

```
public IEnumerable<object> GetAllPeople(string fields)
{
   return (from p in people
           where p.alive == true
           select (the csv fields parameter (ie. fields = Name,Age,Height);
}
```

Yes, I'm using this as sort of a poor mans OData because I can't use OData where I am.

Comment: You are going to need to use expression trees.

Comment: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/linq/

Comment: Can you elaborate the question more; what type is `people` and what exactly do you want to extract from `fields` (a specific field, all the fields, ect.)? Off the cuff I would think you can accomplish what you want by `fields.split(",")`

Comment: @Danny People is just a list of Person objects. I guess I would return object instead of a Person class from this function since ideally fields parameter is a csv list of fields in the Person object that I only want to return instead of returning ALL fields of a Person.

Comment: Your method should return a list of `Person` but your `Select`-statement just returns a subset of the properties of a `Person`? This won´t work at all, either return a `Person` or just parts of it - which would be an anoynmous type which you can´t return effectivly from a method. You might return `IEnumerable<object>`, but what are you doing with the instances within that list? You can´t cast them to their actual type as it was anonymous.

Comment: @HimBromBeere You're right I would have to change from returning Person to returning object. Why do you say "can't return effectively from a method"? I can return object from this I'd just need a dynamic way to build the anonymous type from the linq statement. This is in a web api so the client will deal with the json returned.